# Remove row between table header and row

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/md91vd5k/8/)

This is my jquery :

```
function searchRecords() {
        $('#searchMe').tableutils({
            filter: {
                type: ['noFilter', 'noFilter', 'text']
            },
            fixHeader: {
                width: 1000,
                height: 200
            },

        columns: [{
            label: 'First Name'
        }, {
            label: 'Last Name'
        }, {
            label: 'Concept'
        }, {
            label: 'Rating'
        }, {
            label: 'AKA'
        }]
    });

    $('#searchRecords').hide();
}

searchRecords();

$('#filter_searchMe_2').css('width', '100px').detach().appendTo("#outSide");
```

How can i remove the row between table header and first table row? basically,the area is for filtering for every column but i do not want to filter every column so i remove one textbox for filtering and put it outside the table. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

You can see what i mean on original code for filtering on this [LINK](http://kolgepratik.github.io/tableutils/demo.html),click the **transform** on the **Search through your table category.**

Answer (score 1):

The space below the table header is not a row. It's a gap created due to the `mainTableWrapper_searchMe`'s css attribute `top: 54px;`.
You can override it using the below css:

```
#mainTableWrapper_searchMe
{
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

The `!important` keyword overrides all other rules for specified css property.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hm6xhc/

**EDIT**
You can also use JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mainTableWrapper_searchMe').css('top', '0');
})
```

Comment: thanks! its working, but i dont want the `!important code`,any idea? i think `!important` is not browser friendly and i have to get it work on IE8

Comment: can you explain why `!important` is important? i tried `#mainTableWrapper_searchMe
{
    top: 0;
}` bt nothing happens

Comment: unmark this an answer,because 1 data on table row doesnt show. Try to search `DC`. when using this `#mainTableWrapper_searchMe{top: 0 !important;}` only one item show but it should show two items